# how to determine my coffee script a loop id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

i have loop post in my rails apps each post have comment so i need to determine in my script what post comment will be open here's my code for comment

```
  <div class="comment-action">
                  <%= link_to "Comments", "#" , id: "comments-link-#{post.id}" %>

                   <section class = "comments-section" id = "comments-section-<%= "#{post.id}" %>"  >
                  <br>
                    <%= render 'commenters/newsfeedcomment', obj: post %>

                    <% if current_user == post.user %>
                      <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></h6>
                      <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Delete', { :id => post ,:controller => 'posts',:action => 'destroy'} %></h6>
                    <% end %>
                  </section>
```

you can see the id for comment "comment-link-#{post.id}" and "comment-section-#{post.id}" so will be an unique id for them to call in my script
example if post have an id = 1 then comment-link-1

in my css

```
.comments-section{
display: none;
}
```

here my problem to my script

```
$(document).ready ->
  id = this.id
  $("#comments-link-id").click (event) ->
   event.preventDefault()
   $('#comments-section-id').fadeToggle()
   $('#commenter_body').focus()
```

i dont know how to get a certain id to my script. please share your experience and knowledge so we can help others to thanks

Comment: Is that the real indentation in your CoffeeScript?

Comment: no i just follow the code block in the stockoverflow

Comment: You have to fix it, indentation is everything with CoffeeScript so we can't make sense of your code if you don't fix it.